# Where to locate Virtuemart cart component file on windows directory?

Tags: joomla, content-management-system, directory, shopping-cart, virtuemart

So I want to remove this div class from my homepage (without disabling it for some reason) but I can't find where to locate those files.  Can anyone help me pointed it out?
![enter image description here]

Thank You.

PS: I'm using Joomla 2.5.8 and Virtuemart 2.0.20b
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can remove "shopping cart" module from joomla admin panel by following steps.

Login to admin -> go to Extensions -> Module Manager.
search " VM - Shopping cart " and disable module.